dynamic elements created with document.createElement doesn't have styles in Astro
In my astro file in a script tag I have the following code:
      // create grid of days
      let daysInMonth = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate()
      let week = document.createElement('div')
      week.classList.add('calendar-day-numbers-row')

      for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
        let day = document.createElement('span')
        day.classList.add('calendar-day-number')
        day.innerText = i.toString()
        i == currentDay && day.classList.add('calendar-day-number--current')
        week.append(day)

        if (
          new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, i).getDay() == 6 ||
          i == daysInMonth
        ) {
          document.querySelector('.calendar-day-numbers')?.append(week)

          if (i != daysInMonth) {
            week = document.createElement('div')
            week.classList.add('calendar-day-numbers-row')
          }
        }

As you can see week and day are dynamically created elements and then the classes calendar-day-numbers-row and calendar-day-number are added to week and day respectively
I have styles for those classes in a style tag but only the styles applied to existing static HTML is used.
A look at devtools in the elements tags show that the static HTML have some data attributes that the dynamic elements do not. My guess is this is why the styles are not being applied. Anyway I can fix this issue?

I don't think we can help without seeing the relevant CSS. And have you tried adding in those data attributes?

in astro, styles are scoped to the component by default by astro injecting a data-id to each element. you can make your css global if you're not worried about name space conflicts.

yes, use :global(.calendar-day-numbers-row) in your CSS, or alternatively copy over the data-attributes from existing table rows.
